# Project: Use smartphone as webcam, add AR-filters to videostream, send output as feed to smartphone for further usage within mobile app

Tags: streaming, filter

If the title is leaving you with a big "!!?!" then... my bad... I am lacking the needed vocabulary I guess. lol PLUS... I don't know if what I am trying is even feasible.

**Here's what I want:**

I am using an app on my mobilephone, within which I can create a live stream - just like twitch, yt, ig, ... you name it. Since I am using the phone for the video, I am basically setting it up like a webcam, which makes it kinda hard to still take part in the chat. Additionally I want to add AR-effects to my video, which this app doesn't provide by itself.

✅ **Goal 1:** I wanted to remote control my smartphone from my Laptop to be able to use the chat, while my phone was setup for the stream. I am using an open source tool (scrcpy) to mirror my android phone to my laptop. So this step is covered.

⏳ **Goal 2:** Unfortunately said app offers very limited filters and no AR to make the streaming experience more entertaining. Which is why I came up with the idea of using tools on my laptop that use my smartphone as webcam, pimp the videostream with AR effects, which then is sent to my mobile as kind of default camera output(?), in order for said streaming app to recognize that incoming stream as default video source.

**Here's what I've tried:**

1. OBS Studio allows me to use my smartphone as videosource as if it was a webcam.
2. I am using a 2nd tool that recognizes the video output from OBS studio (virtual camera) and adds effects to it.
3. Now I want to use this video output as video source for my app on my smartphone when I start a stream.

**OR...**

Is there maybe a different and simpler solution to this?

[image]